# How to add power switch to Adafruit Feather32?

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, esp32, hardware, adafruit

I have an Adafruit HUZZAH32 ESP32 board, a battery and an on/off switch. I'd like to connect them in such a way that all of the following are satisfied:

1. Switch turns the board on/off
2. Board is powered by battery or USB
3. USB connection to board charges the battery, regardless of the switch state

I could just put the switch in between battery and board, but then I'd need to close the switch to charge.

Comment: study the board circuit schematic diagram ... insert the switch between the usb/battery junction and the rest of the circuit

Answer (score 2):

All Feather boards have an "EN" pin which stands for "Enable". Simply put your switch between the EN pin and GND (to pull the EN pin low) and the voltage regulator will be disabled when you close the switch.

This is the documented and correct way to use a power switch with Feather boards.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather/pinouts

> EN - this is the 3.3V regulator's enable pin. It's pulled up, so connect to ground to disable the 3.3V regulator